# Turning a Xamarin Android Number Picker Sideways

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using the Android number picker in a Xamarin.Forms application (inserting the native control) but I'd like to turn it sideways so that the plus is on the left and the minus is on the right.  Is this easy/possible?

[image]

changed to

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the [Syncfusion Numeric Up/Down](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/numericupdown) control?

[image]

They also allow [split button alignment](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfnumericupdown/spin-button-alignment#both) to get your desired look:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [documentation for the `NumberPicker` class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.NumberPicker/), your request is not currently supported. Xamarin basically just implemented a wrapper around the [native implementation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html), where it is also not supported. This tells me, that this is the standard behaviour for this type of control for Android.

Conclusively, you would have to create your own custom widget to support this.